# Blazor server app with cors enabled still blocking requests

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app with the following configurations in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "NewPolicy",
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                  .AllowAnyMethod()
                                  .AllowAnyHeader();

                      });
});
...
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("NewPolicy");
```

I added a video under wwwroot, which I'm trying to access via a client app. The idea is to stream it through a MediaSource object. Here's a code snippet:

```
<body>
    <video controls></video>
    <script>
      var video = document.querySelector('video');

      var assetURL = 'https://localhost:7113/video1.mp4';
      var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

      if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
        var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
        mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
      } else {
        console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
      }

      function sourceOpen (_) {
        var mediaSource = this;
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        fetchAB(assetURL, function (buf) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
            mediaSource.endOfStream();
            video.play();
          });
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
        });
      };

      function fetchAB (url, cb) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
        xhr.open('get', url);
        xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
        xhr.onload = function () {
          cb(xhr.response);
        };
        xhr.send();
      };
    </script>
  </body>
```

Im always getting the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:7113/viedo1.mp4' from origin 'http://localhost:8080/testclient' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I checked the configuration over and over again, it seems exactly as specified by MSDN. Also setting the video `src` attribute to the video's remote path works fine but it fails when using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got to resolve this with the help of this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

All content under www root are static files that need extra configuration in order to be accessed through http calls without throwing that cors issue.

In program.cs, I modified the following line:

`app.UseStaticFiles();`

to this:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(
    new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        OnPrepareResponse = ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Context.Response.Headers.Append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        }
    }
);
```

Now this tells http client that whenever there is an http call for these files to append the `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` header to the response.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: You are simply removing a security, why can't you make calls through HTTPS instead?